# Thymeleaf - can th:checked and th:field be used together?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

In my `Java 11`, `Spring Boot 2.7.4` application, I use `Spring MVC` and `Thymeleaf` to bind server objects to HTML pages. This generally works very well but I am struggling with a checkbox issue.

In the model, I have a map containing file names (String) and whether the file is restricted or not (boolean). I represent this in a table within a form in the following code snippet, which works fine:

```
<tr th:each="data_set, iStat: ${resultSet.data}">
       <td th:text="${data_set.rawDataMap.get('filename')}" />
       <td>
              <div class="form-check">
                     <input class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            th:checked="${data_set.rawDataMap.get('isRestricted') == 1 ? true : false}"
                            value="permissions-check"
                     >
                     <!--Other fields below-->
              </div>
       </td>
</tr>
```

However, I want the user to be able to check/uncheck the checkbox and submit the form to a controller so that the permissions may be changed. To do this, I want to bind the checkbox to another object on the model in order to capture any changes that the user may make. To do this I added one extra line, the th:field section on line 9 below:

```
<tr th:each="data_set, iStat: ${resultSet.data}">
       <td th:text="${data_set.rawDataMap.get('filename')}" />
       <td>
              <div class="form-check">
                     <input class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            th:checked="${data_set.rawDataMap.get('isRestricted') == 1 ? true : false}"
                            value="permissions-check"
                            th:field="*{data[__${iStat.index}__].targetIsRestricted}">
                     <!--Other fields below-->
              </div>
       </td>
</tr>
```

This works in capturing the user changes, which are sent correctly to the server. The issue is that the `th:checked` section (line 7) no longer works. All checkboxes now appear unticked. So it appears that I can use either `th:checked` or `th:field`, but not both together. On the server side, I have tried making the targetIsRestricted variable on the model object a String, boolean and Object, but none have worked so far. I would be very grateful to receive any suggestions. Many thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use `th:checked` with `th:field`.  Why don't you set the value of `data[__${iStat.index}__].targetIsRestricted = data_set.rawDataMap.get('isRestricted')`  in your controller?